# How does one usually deal with this kind of loop processes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, propagator, electroweak

[image: These loops]

Now, I ask this because of the propagator of the inner line of the lepton going through a loop. Let's assume the initial Z has a momentum $p$, and the outgoing leptons have a momentum $p_1$ (for the one with the loop) and $p_2$ (for the other one).

Wouldn't the momentum going through the propagator of the virtual lepton before the loop be $$\dfrac{1}{(p-p_2)^2 - m^2} = \dfrac{1}{p_1^2 - m^2} = \dfrac{1}{0}~???$$

My initial guess on how to solve this issue is to treat the loop in isolation, just calculate the contribution of the loop to the propagator and add it to the final decay. Would this work?

And, if it did work, would this also work if the loop changes the flavour of the particle? For example, in interactions between $W$ bosons and quarks, you could get a diagram of a $u$ quark "changing" to a $c$ quark or a $t$ quark.

Comment: Indeed the non looped propagator denominator vanishes when evaluated at the mass, but so too does the self energy term. You'd have something like $\lim_{\not{p}\to m}\frac{\Sigma(\not{p})}{\not{p}-m}$ which is indeterminate.

Comment: In this process and all others, the momenta that can be taken on-shell are the external ones. If you do this, the residue of the $\frac{1}{p_1^2 - m^2}$ pole is what's most relevant because that defines the scattering amplitude.